# How to disable auto sort when creating a set in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to fill a set with 100 random integers. But when i do it, python automatically sort the set for me. I want to load the set as is, so i can have a chance to learn. Is there a better way of doing it (*making a set of random int from a range, with each int occurring only once*)

P.S I am writing the set to a text file as well.

```
import random
noDuplicate = set()
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    while noDuplicate.__len__() < 100: 
       noDuplicate.add(random.randint(0,100))
    for i in noDuplicate:
       f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes, sets are not ordered at all.

Comment: You can consider using ``collections.OrderedDict`` as an "ordered set", which remembers the order in which the elements are inserted when you iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments and other answers, `sets` are not ordered, so would be the wrong collection type to use.  I guess you want to use them because you don't want duplicates in the resulting collection.

If you have a collection of elements, and want to pick x many of these with no duplicates, probably the best feature to use is `random.sample`.

```
import random
possible_numbers = range(0, 101) # Note randint is inclusive of both ends
no_duplicate = random.sample(possible_numbers, 100)
```

You will end up with a list (i.e. ordered) and will not see any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `make a set of random int from a range`. I think you should use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

```
>>> a = range(0, 5)
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> print a
[3, 0, 4, 1, 2]
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> print a
[4, 3, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets are not intended to use in cases when you care about elements order. This collection is used when you have to check if some element is in set or not, also they support useful logical operations like intersection etc. If you care about elements order — probably you should use another collection type.

For example, you can use list:

```
import random
no_duplicate = []
while len(no_duplicate) < 100:
    i = random.randint(0, 100)
    if i not in no_duplicate:
        no_duplicate.append(i)
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in no_duplicate))
```